Getting "RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED" when trying to select open Excel workbook and save it as is
I'm a newbie so please bear with me.
I'm trying to put together a script that will force save an already open Excel spreadsheet every five minutes but every time I run it I get an "RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED" error. The Spreadsheet will be open 24/7 so it doesn't need to be opened anew.
Below is my script:
$excel = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')
$excel.Visible = $true
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open("workbook location")
$workbook.Save()
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel) | Out-Null

This is the full error I get:
Call was rejected by callee. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED))
At line:2 char:1
+ $excel.Visible = $false
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:3 char:1
+ $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open("workbook location ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
 
The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
At line:4 char:1
+ $workbook.Save()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException


This error seems to happen with all Microsoft Office Products.  One posting says it is due to versions being incompatible.  What version of Interop are you using?  What version of Office?  I suspect the version of Office and the version of the Interop are not compatible and is not directly a Powershell issue.  See : https://community.myob.com/discussions/sales_and_purchases/error-trying-to-export-report-to-excel-80010001-call-was-rejected-by-callee/745263

@jdweng My office version is Office 2016. Not sure about the interop version.

Interop should be in a folder like : C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\15
